# Functions satisfying differential equation of the Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, elliptic-functions

The Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp$ satisfies the following differential equation: $${\wp'}^2 = 4 \wp^3 - g_2 \wp - g_3$$
Which other functions do?

Are the solutions always elliptic functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given theorem on existence and uniquenes of solutions to ordinary differential equations (**Picard's theorem**) there is only one local solution if the **Lipschitz condition** is satisfied, in fact it is when we take $x_1$,$x_2$ in the same parallelogram (determined with $(g_2,g_3)$) away from the lattice points. Since $\wp$ is doubly periodic it determines the solution everywhere (the lattice points are the second order poles).

Rewriting the equation one can reformulate  the definition of the Weierstrass elliptic function, i.e. $\wp(x;g_2,g_3)$ yields the value $z$ for which
$$x=\int_{\infty}^{z} \frac{d t}{\sqrt{4t^3-g_2 t-g_3}}  $$

Reassuming there is only one solution if an initial condition is prescribed appropriately and it is just $\wp(x\pm c;g_2,g_3)$, where $c$ can be determined from the initial condition. If we prescribe e.g. this condition $f(\infty)=0$, then there are no solutions unless $\;g_2=0=g_3$.

In a degenerate case $g_2=g_3=0$ the only solution is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\left(x \pm c\right)^2}$ and this may be considered as non-elliptic function since it is not periodic, elliptic functions are doubly periodic meromorphic functions in the complex plane.